# UIView to show a particular facebook fan page newsfeed

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to design a UIView to show a particular Facebook fan page's newsfeed on my app. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook fan pages have RSS feed that you can access programmatically and parse it on your UI view
RSS url should look like so:
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=PAGE_ID&format=rss20

hope this helps